# LLDB cannot print local variables or access them: no member named 'table' in namespace '$__lldb_local_vars'

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

When attempting to print out a custom hash map variable named "table" I seem to get this error with lldb:

```
error: expression failed to parse:
error: <lldb wrapper prefix>:45:31: no member named 'table' in namespace '$__lldb_local_vars'
    using $__lldb_local_vars::table;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
error: <user expression 2>:1:1: use of undeclared identifier 'table'
```

YES the variable is declared in this scope and in fact when switching to my laptop I can use LLDB just fine and print out the table contents.

I also notice other issues when printing out a different vector. It is clearly populated when adding print statements however when using lldb to print out the vector it shows it as unpopulated and all of size 0.

I am running Fedora 35 and I have tried updating and reinstalling lldb. As I said before, my laptop is able to print everything out just fine.

I have also tried following this post:
[LLDB gives "use of undeclared identifier" error for local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050606/lldb-gives-use-of-undeclared-identifier-error-for-local-variable)

using image lookup -va $pc yields the following results indicating that the table is present:

```
Variable: id = {0x00018088}, name = "table", type = "HashTable &", location = DW_OP_fbreg -904, decl = main.cpp:113:24
```

I can share the chunk of code giving me problems but I am not sure it is relevant. I simply pass this variable into the function by reference and print it. I can print it no where else in the program.

Note:
This extends beyond printing, I cannot access the size, capacity, or anything else relating to the 'table' variable. LLDB just throws this error.

Also perhaps on an unrelated note I noticed a few weeks ago that clearly deleted objects were still showing up and printable in LLDB. I could still access the variable and manipulate the data and what not but it was very clearly deleted. Again perhaps unrelated I suspected it was just that LLDB hadn't updated the variable list or something of this nature but it cost me a bit of time figuring out why the variable wasn't deleted.

Thanks for any help in advance

**EDIIT:**
Compiling with clang++ seems to fix my issue on my desktop? I could just use clang instead of g++ but I still am curious how this difference in compilers changes it? I suppose I understand it fundamentally but using g++ and lldb works without issue on my laptop. Is using lldb and g++ together a big no no?
(I must use lldb on my laptop as it is an M1 and only supports lldb I believe so I just opted to use lldb on my desktop as well)

Comment: Does this [lldb cannot print values in debug code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337821/lldb-cannot-print-values-in-debug-code) answer your question?

Comment: @273K I didnt mention it in the post but I also looked at this post as well it did not fix the issue. After some more investigating it seems compiling with clang++ seems to fix my issue? Really strange in my opinion. Works on my laptop with g++ perfectly fine. Updated post

Comment: Try various `-g` options, one of `-gdwarf-2`, `-gdwarf-3`, `-gdwarf-4`, `-gdwarf-5` should work.

Comment: @273K Unfortunately, this hasn't worked...

Comment: The g++/lldb combo isn't as well tested as clang++/lldb, since the latter combo's testing gates submissions to clang & lldb but not to gcc...  But it's all DWARF, so short of bugs or unexpected quirks in the debug info emission, clang & gcc should be interchangeable.

Comment: The "image lookup" output you posted showed the variable located at -906 bytes from the frame pointer.  That's a pretty big stack frame, though not crazy big.  But if the function you are in doesn't have lots of big locals or arguments, that suggests a debug info bug.  When you compile the same code with clang++, where does `image lookup` stopped at the same point say this variable is?  If the two values are widely different, then it probably is a bug either in gcc's debug info emission, or it's using some variant of the location that lldb doesn't support yet.

Comment: @JimIngham The table says 8 bytes with clang and it is at the same location: DW_OP_fbreg

Comment: If you want to follow this further, you'll need to file a bug.  If gdb also misreports the value, then file something on gcc, since its own debugger gets the value wrong.  If gdb handles it, then there's probably some construct that lldb doesn't expect, in which case, file it on lldb.  You'll have to provide some example that shows the problem, with your build products.